# Проблемы с рекурсией

Tags: python, рекурсия

вот код который должен из многомерных списков сделать один список:

```
def one_level_flatten(value: list):
    filter_value = list(filter(lambda x: x is not [], value))
    flatten_values = list()
    for i in filter_value:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            for j in i:
                flatten_values.append(j)
        else:
            flatten_values.append(i)
    return flatten_values


def flatten(*args):
    sequence = [i for i in args]
    if list in list(map(type, sequence)):
        return flatten(one_level_flatten(sequence))
    else:
        return sequence
```

Это рекурсивная программа. Если честно, это задача с codewars.

Вопрос : почему мне выдает ошибку, что рекурсия сработала 992 раза, если максимальная многомерность списков в тесте не больше 5?  В программе все проверки работают, и работа в рекурсией безопасна.

```
print(one_level_flatten([[], 11, 22, [], [1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]]))
print(one_level_flatten(one_level_flatten([[], 11, 22, [], [1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]])))
```

Результат функции `one_level_flatten`. То есть ошибка в функции flatten:

```
[11, 22, 1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]
[11, 22, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Вот тесты с codewars

```
@test.describe('Example Tests')
def example_tests():
    test.assert_equals(flatten(),[])
    test.assert_equals(flatten(1,2,3),[1,2,3])
    test.assert_equals(flatten([1,2],[3,4,5],[6,[7],[[8]]]),[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
    test.assert_equals(flatten(1,2,['9',[],[]],None),[1,2,'9',None])
    test.assert_equals(flatten(['hello',2,['text',[4,5]]],[[]],'[list]'),['hello',2,'text',4,5,'[list]'])
```

Вот ошыбка

[image: RecursionError]

Comment: Когда вы вызываете функцию `flatten`, вы передаёте в неё первым аргументом результат вызова `one_level_flatten` — то есть список. Но `args` сам по себе тоже является списком, и первый аргумент функции становится первым элементом в этом списке. А так как первый аргумент это список из one_level_flatten, то значит `args` это список внутри списка, и отсюда получается бесконечная рекурсия

Comment: Код ужасен. Что делает `x is not []`? Что делает `[i for i in args]`?

Comment: `flatten(one_level_flatten(sequence))` -> `flatten(*one_level_flatten(sequence))`

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy  код очень хороший ,   ```x is not [] ``` проверяет не пустой ли список  , а             ``` [i for i in args] ``` складывает списки , ведь в тестах же показано что может быть ситуация где несколько списков передаються в функцию

Comment: Код очень хороший. Одна проблема — не работает.

Comment: Смотри в тест там всё понятно что должна делать ваша функция.

Comment: дайте пожалуйста ссылку на кату, любопытство проснулось )

Comment: https://www.codewars.com/kata/513fa1d75e4297ba38000003/train/python

Comment: @andriy-byte, `x is not []` всегда возвращает `True`. Вам повезло, что этот кусок вообще ни на что не влияет. `[i for i in args]` равносильно копированию списка `list(args)`. В вашем случае - бесполезная копия.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy спасибо , я оптимизировал код.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/9210255

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, там речь только про два уровня вложенности. А нужна произвольная вложенность.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, может вопрос и про два уровня вложенности, но кто-то кто отвечал пошел дальше и предложил решение для нескольких уровней вложенности, к примеру [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40252152/9210255)

Answer (score 1):

Рассмотрим простой пример. Что вернёт вот это?

```
one_level_flatten([])
```

А оно вернёт `[]`. Т.е. то же самое, что ей дали на вход. Соответственно, конструкция

```
def flatten(*args):
    sequence = [i for i in args]
    if list in list(map(type, sequence)):
        return flatten(one_level_flatten(sequence))
```

Будет крутиться бесконечно. Потому как на первой итерации `sequence[0]` равна '[]' и это `list`. На второй итерации эта переменная опять такая же, так что снова входит в рекурсию. И так до бесконечности.

Раз вы используете `*args` как список, то самый "плоский" список для функции `flatten()` будет просто аргументы. А самый "плоский" вид, который возвращает функция `one_level_flatten()` - это список. Соответственно, чтобы передать список как аргументы, надо просто использовать оператор разложения по аргументам `*`:

```
flatten(*one_level_flatten(sequence))
```

Ну и вообще, весь код в принципе вырождается в одну строчку :)

```
def flatten(*args):
    return flatten(*sum([i if isinstance(i, list) else [i] for i in args], [])) if list in list(map(type, args)) else list(args)
```

Comment: `sum` на списках порождает квадратичный алгоритм.